# Python: How do I delete periods occurring alone in a CSV file?

Tags: python, text, csv, replace, missing-data

I have a bunch of CSV files.  In some of them, missing data are represented by empty cells, but in others there is a period.  I want to loop over all my files, open them, delete any periods that occur alone, and then save and close the file.

I've read a bunch of other questions about doing whole-word-only searches using re.sub().  That is what I want to do (delete . when it occurs alone but not the . in 3.5), but I can't get the syntax right for a whole-word-only search where the whole word is a special character ('.').  Also, I'm worried those answers might be a little different in the case where a whole word can be distinguished by tab and newlines too.  That is, does /b work in my CSV file case?

UPDATE: Here is a function I wound up writing after seeing the help below.  Maybe it will be useful to someone else.

```
import csv, re

def clean(infile, outfile, chars):

''' 
Open a file, remove all specified special characters used to represent missing data, and save.\n\n
infile:\tAn input file path\n
outfile:\tAn output file path\n
chars:\tA list of strings representing missing values to get rid of
'''

in_temp = open(infile)
out_temp = open(outfile, 'wb')

csvin = csv.reader(in_temp)
csvout = csv.writer(out_temp)
for row in csvin:
    row = re.split('\t', row[0])
    for colno, col in enumerate(row):
        for char in chars:
            if col.strip() == char:
                row[colno] = ''
    csvout.writerow(row)

in_temp.close()
out_temp.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick... This data wouldn't happen to be coming out of SAS would it - IIRC, that quite often used '.' as missing for numeric values.

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csvin:
        for colno, col in enumerate(row):
            if col.strip() == '.':
                row[colno] = ''
        csvout.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  The data is from the Federal Reserve.  I wouldn't be surprised if they used SAS or something like that.  The frustrating thing was that for whatever reason the different files are a little inconsistent in how they represent missing data.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the csv module?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

with open(somefile) as infile:
  r=csv.reader(infile)
  rows = []
  for row in csv:
    rows.append(['' if f == "." else f for f in row])
with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile:
  w=csv.writer(outfile)
  w.writelines(rows)
```

Comment: Any reason to create an in-memory list before commencing any output?

Comment: @Jon nope, your answer's better. So there.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would be to use the CSV module to process the file, then identify any fields that only contain `.`, delete those and write the new CSV file back to disk.

A brittle workaround would be to search and replace a dot that is not surrounded by alphanumerics: `\B\.\B` is the regex that would find those dots. But that might also find other dots like the middle dot in `"..."`.

So, to find a dot that is surrounded by commas, you could search for `(?<=,)\.(?=,)`.